# SproutCore Ace for jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sproutcore

Does anybody know if there is a port of the SproutCore Ace theme to jQuery UI?

link:

http://www.sproutcore.com/

Comment: If you end up rolling your own, do please consider sharing it — even if it’s incomplete, simply note that up-front in the documentation and slap it up on GitHub!

Answer (score 3):

I think you might already know of these, but here's a link to a [compilation of beautiful themes](http://dailyjs.com/2010/09/21/jquery-roundup/) on top of jQuery UI, including Aristo and Absolution

Answer (score 0):

nope, but you can build your own.